# Safari 13.1 refused to load Shopify embeded applications

Tags: safari, shopify, content-security-policy

Our application was working just fine, but recent changes in Safari caused our application to break.

Safari 13.1 starts blocking applications embedded in Shopify using an iframe.

The error it throws is:

```
        refused to load https://xxdddddd.com/admin/auth/login because it does not appear in the frame-ancestor directive of content security policy.
```

We tried all sorts of content security policy and chrome and Firefox works just fine but safari always breaks,

We removed that header altogether.

We even added:

```
header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' img-src * data:");

header("Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe");
header("Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate");
header("Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site");
```

We tried all sorts of combinations, but it failed every time in Safari. I can find that several of other applications work just fine in embedded mode in Shopify and Safari 13.1, so it definitely means it is possible.

One thing I noticed is that the URL needs to be changed post authorization and in our cast it is not changing as Safari blocks, but in other applications it changes the URL in the browser. However I found nothing different in their code using view-source. I tried to replicate all headers as well. They are giving, but nothing worked,

Answer (score 0):

Your CSP `frame-ancestors * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' img-src * data:` is completely wrong:

- directives blocks should be comma-separated
- the frame-ancestors directive does not supports 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' tokens,

Correct syntax CSP should look like `frame-ancestors *; img-src * data:;`

But the paradox is that this wrong CSP does allow frame-ancestors from any sources. After removing all unsupported sources, the effective CSP is `frame-ancestors * data:` in your case.

In the error:

```
refused to load https://xxdddddd.com/admin/auth/login because it does not appear in the frame-ancestor directive of content security policy.
```

confuses two things:

1. phrase `in the frame-ancestor directive` contains wrong directive name (**s** is omitted at the end of directive name). Is this a real Safari browser error?
2. the `/admin/auth/` part - is this really public accessible URL? Or does this error appear in the administrator script, which could have other CSP rules?

You say in Chrome and Firefox all worked fine, but `frame-ancestors * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' img-src * data:` rules disallow images loading from any sources.
So it's possible you are editing one CSP header, but the app really have another. If you are familiar with the Safari browser console, you could check real CSP HTTP header delivered to the app's page.

Anyway, [here](http://csplite.com/csp/test221/) you could test does Safari 13.1 support * in frame-ancestors (I can't do that due to Safari browser absence). It will exclude a case of a current version browser bug.

Comment: its not working. i tried all sorts of csp combination including yours it does not work. same error still

Comment: @turkyoung did you find a solution? I am running into exactly the same problem